Can't change copy shortcut in MobaXTerm
I recently started using MobaXterm on Windows, but since I come from a GNOME background, I'm used to Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V for copy/paste.
I tried changing the default shortcuts for these, but the keyboard shortcuts page only allows changing "Paste in terminal". I can't find the place to change copy!
Is there a way to change the copy shortcut? A config file somewhere?
Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts settings page:


That’s because Copy is handled by Windows.

@Ramhound but that hasn't stopped PuTTY from allowing three shortcuts (including ctrl+shift+c) from being used for copy.

Are you saying that within MobaXterm which i used routinely daily for hours, that CTRL+Shift+C doesn’t work?

@Ramhound I will have to try again tomorrow since I'm not at work, and I may be mistaken, but earlier when I tried ctrl+shift+c it would insert ^C instead of copying.

What version of MobaXterm?

@Ramhound v24.1. Also, I checked again and ctrl+shift+c DOES indeed copy, but it also inserts ^C which is very inconvenient. I should have checked this before posting this question.

So I use MobaXterm, and I routinely copy things from the console, and I don't have ^C inserted.  This suggests this might be a session configuration issue.
